# How to reference User foreign key in template?

Tags: django, django-models

I can't seem to grasp this very well. So I have an Album model, which is using a class based view and I'm giving it the context with all objects:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    # Columns
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.FileField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
```

The default was put to see if it was working within the Admin page, which it did. On every Album object there was a user field, but when I tried to display it on a template, it wasn't showing.

```
{% for album in all_albums %}
<h2>{{ album.album_title }}</h2>
<h4>{{ album.artist }}</h4>
<h6 class="text-muted">Created by: {{ album.user }}</h6>
{% endfor %}
```

The album_title and artist displayed just fine, but not the User (str is username). When I tried getting it up on the shell, I got this:

```
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

EDIT:
I just noticed this. On the template tag I do this:

```
<h6 class="text-muted">Created by: {{ album.user_id }}</h6>
```

And it does display the user id that corresponds to that individual Album. But there's no method for the username or the email, etc.

Comment: Bet 1$ that you're building the `Album` model instance without passing a `User` models. The `default=1` is ensure you're pointing to a possible "nowhere". So make sure you're actually passing a valid `User` instance or at least you will always have a `User` instance with PK equals to 1.

Comment: @vyscond I did import User model. Sorry if you misunderstood on the question, but I mentioned that on the Admin page, I can actually see the user's field in each Album and they all have the user with id=1 assigned to it.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi I don't have it customized. It's django.contrib.auth.models.User.

Comment: @Nifled Try {{ album.user.username }} and  {{ album.user.email }}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it:

```
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

Apparently the user id stored in the foreign key column of the album table does not exist in the user table. It's best to not have dead foreign key relations, then you won't have these errors.

However, it might still happen sometimes. You can protect yourself against it like this:

```
try:
    user = album.user
except DoesNotExist:
    user = None
```

In templates you unfortunately cannot do this. So you'll have to do it in python and pass it in the template context or you could make a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) where you put these try except lines.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the whole dead foreign key relations. I started manually changing the user field in every album object and it's displaying everything now.

Answer (score 1):

Well Hello There.

Let's look at this question from the information you gave us.

You are trying to reference a model within your template and access that models foreign key values.

example

```
record = Example.objects.get()
# pass into context
context = {"record": record}
#
# now we access in template
{{ record.user.username }}
```

Make sure you are getting the record. "DoesNotExist" seems to indicate you haven't correctly queried, or the record you are searching for is not correct, check username and password and auth settings.

Make sure you pass it to the context of the template hence "record". You access the foreign relations by  {{ record.user (object) }} 
{{ record.user.username (ex. id, username, email, etc.) }}